# Cancel comment filter?

Tags: comments

Is it possible to cancel comment submission if certain creteria are met?

I want to limit the number of characters in a comment. Where do I test the length and cancel the comment if it's over a given length?

Would the pre_comment_approved filter do this? And does anyone have some sample code for how to use pre_comment_approved ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are certainly on the right track. You can [create a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers) (create a directory in "wp-content/plugins" and create a php file with the same name as the folder) with the following code:

```
function wpse_33944_filter_handler( $approved , $commentdata ){
    if(strlen($commentdata[comment_content]) > 5) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved' , 'wpse_33944_filter_handler' , '99', 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Do I need to make it a plugin? Or can I chuck the code in functions.php in the theme I'm working on?

Comment: You can probably chuck it in functions.php. But creating it as a plugin seems cleaner :)